# Using negative height in g.fillRect()

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to paint a bar graph using g.fillRect() to make each bar.

The bars will start at the grid height, y: 700, and fill upwards to y: 350 for example.

I am unable to set a negative x-height for my bar:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (Bar b : this.bars) {
        g.fillRect(b.x_location,b.y_location,b.width,b.height * (-1));
    }
}
```

This won't paint the bars.

**Fix:**

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (Bar b : this.bars) {
        g.fillRect(b.x_location,b.y_location - b.height,b.width,b.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, because of the way the API works, in extends down and to the right. Instead, subtract the distance from the `y` coordinate and maintain the height as a positive value

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645172/java-draws-rectangle-one-way-not-both/22645343#22645343)

Comment: This works, tyvm.

I subtracted the height of the bar from our y-coordinate and it did just what it needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because of the way the API works, it extends down and to the right. Instead, subtract the distance from the `y` coordinate and maintain the height as a positive value

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-)

> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.

While not a direct duplicate, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645172/java-draws-rectangle-one-way-not-both/22645343#22645343) demonstrates the basic concepts