# Java - why is my movement algorithm having exaggerated movements?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse, drag

I'm trying to implement a dragging algorithm for swing components where they can be clicked and dragged. However, it appears that my movements are in the correct directions, but extremely exaggerated. As in, a tiny bit of mouse movement causes a very disproportionate move in the shape.

Here is the code where I determine the movement:

(`xStart` and `yStart` are the coordinates where the mouse is first clicked to begin the drag)

The component has a `move(int deltaX, int delatY)` method which does just that. An example move method for a line component looks like this:

```
@Override
public void move(int dx, int dy) {
    this.x1 += dx;
    this.y1 += dy;
    this.x2 += dx;
    this.y2 += dy;
}
```

The move method is called like this, where `e` is a mouse drag event:

```
currentShape.move(e.getX() - (int) xStart, e.getY() - (int) yStart);
```

Comment: Well, [that's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904865/when-i-mouse-drag-to-draw-a-circle-the-shape-moves-in-certain-situations/43946668#43946668), [that's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476645/resizing-path2d-circle-by-clicking-and-dragging-its-outer-edge/26476909#26476909), [that's another possible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108351/getting-the-starting-x-and-y-coordinates-of-a-path2d-shape-drawn-on-jpanel/26112443#26112443)

Comment: The real question is. how are the details calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have your `dx` `dy` values equal the change in the cursors movement from the last mouse event you received and not the change from where the shape was initially clicked on.

I would recommend making a `keyframeX` and `keyframeY` variable to store your last mouse event `x` and `y` values to compare against.

Comment: I actually figured this out a few minutes ago, but your answer is correct, so I accepted it.